# magento 1.9 Navigation left side menu keeps going to middle column

Tags: magento-1.9, navigation

Problem I'm having;

I'm trying to add a Left sidebar navigation, I got advice yesterday to edit my layout.xml, catalog.xml and create a myleft.phtml file. I even set the layout to 2 column with left bar in the back end. I have done all of this but still no left navigation. So I installed [this addon](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sidebar-navigation-menu-professional.html)

Which even though I set in the back end settings to "left column" it still ends up on the top above all other content [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GB8o.png)

I will post a new comment with my layout.xml and catalog.xml as I can't post any more characters

Thanks,
Stephen

Comment: My catalog.xml file is uploaded here; http://textuploader.com/5zsdn

Comment: My myleft.phtml file is uploaded here; http://textuploader.com/5zs1s

Comment: I even created a local.xml in the same directory as the catalog.xml which is here; http://textuploader.com/5zs1k

Comment: Your local.xml isn't correct. Your not closing the reference tag, you're opening a new one. This makes your XML invalid. Fix that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be due to several issues *(css isn't useful for the question I recommend you to remove it and add the *-layout-.xml* where you are adding the block and it path to)*

1. If you are using de 'RWD' theme and the extension was written for he 'default' the extension layout will not be loaded.
2. Same if you already have created a local.xml file in your theme
3. Ensure that you are adding the block to the left block

   **ie:**

`<reference name="left">
   <block name="your_block">....</block>
</reference>`

**EDIT:**

Looking at the image you've attached seems to be a sass/css problem you must change the css classes definition for that media-query. In RWD magento add the filters over the catalog for viewports smaller than xxx px.

Check your sass files to find the breakpoints vars, you can see the changes in the DOM using the mobile simulator of google chrome: and clicking blue, green and orange bars in the top:

[image]

[Here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_dev-guide.html) you'll find a complete guide about the RWD theme.

Comment: Do I add that code to the backend or my catalog.xml? Because it is definitely in my catalog pointing to LEFT reference. Also that addon does work with rwd theme according to their support page.

Comment: The layout file in which the menu block  is included

Comment: Edited the catalog.xml to;
<reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml">
            </block>
        </reference>
And still does not show in the left column, as shown in the imgur link in top post

Comment: ok seems to be ok, can you see the menu html inside the `<div class="col-left ..."`

Comment: Which file am I looking at?

Comment: i was talking about html generated in the browser, check out my answer update, Im pretty sure that this is the problem

Comment: Viewing the source reveals there is nothing inside <div class="col-left..."
As shown here;
                <div class="col-left sidebar"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

I will try and have another look within the .css but Ive tried before and not found anything there specifically

Comment: Yes it's exactly what i saying in the answer edit... when you change to a smaller viewport the <col-left> contents are moved to the <main> i'm pretty sure that you have some misconfiguration in compass project setup: take a look at your viewports configuration at: `[root]/skin/frontend/[package]/[theme]/scss/_var.scss` $bp-xsmall, $bp-small etc...

Comment: Ok cool we are getting somehwere! These are my current values;
$bp-xsmall: 479px;
$bp-small: 599px;
$bp-medium: 770px;
$bp-large: 979px;
$bp-xlarge: 1199px;

Is there a way to not set it a fixed width, as in dynamic or something else?
If you'd like to view the site yourself it's currently setup at www.pc-tek.com.au

Comment: well breakpoints configuration depends on your responsive design ideas, i'll let you a link to the official magento rwd design guide in the answer, but resolve your design is out my scope.

Comment: Cheers dude, thankyou